# Custom UIScrollView backing a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have some custom scrolling behavior I would like to use in a few different places. Let's say the scroll view should provide for the following three behaviors:

- change color as the user scrolls, dependent on the content offset.
- expose an imageView property which is displayed in the background. The consumer can set the image.
- let a delegate know when the content offset exceeds some fixed value.

I have a working implementation using a `UIScrollView` subclass. But now I would like the same functionality in a `UITableView`, which of course is backed by a standard `UIScrollView`.

How might I re-use the same code in both places? The closest I have come so far is to turn off the tableview's scrolling and also force its height to always match its content size. Then I can add it to my custom scroll view like any other view. This works, but has some drawbacks.

Could I implement this using a category? A protocol? Can I 'swap out' `UITableView`'s scroll view somehow for my own? Any other techniques I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for you.

Make a class for implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate methods - let's say (of course choose a better name...):

```
@interface ScrollViewDelegateHelper : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Make a class for implementing all the UITableViewDelegate methods (and of course dataSource methods if you like), let's say:

```
@interface TableViewDelegateHelper : ScrollViewDelegateHelper <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

The **TableViewDelegateHelper** extends **ScrollViewDelegateHelper**, so all the scroll events can be written in one file. 
And you can use **ScrollViewDelegateHelper** in both cases, one time as the delegate for your custom UIScrollView, and the second time as the parent of the delegate of your TableView

Hope it helps.